# ShallowWrapper selector in enzyme

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, enzyme, jestjs

i am using enzyme (airbnb) library for finding wrapper.my html is like

```
<div>
 <div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
</div>
```

i have to choose nested three divs using enzyme library using find function.Is it possible using enzyme find method ??

Comment: Did you try it out?

Comment: Is this the [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378)?

Answer (score 3):

The `find` method accepts css selectors so you could use `wrapper.find('div > div')`

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to add a similar class to all the nested divs. In that way you can access all the three divs together. I think this will be the cleanest way to do it. Assuming you name this component 'MyComponent'. Test suite will  be:

```
 <div>
   <div className="sameclass"></div>
  <div className="sameclass"></div>
    <div className="sameclass"></div>
</div>

describe('MyComponent', () => {
  it('length of nested divs must be 3', () => {    
   const wrapper = mount(<Mycomponent/>)
    expect(wrapper.find('.sameclass').length).toEqual('3');      
     });
   })
```

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend to do that sort of find in your tests. If you do that, your test will be highly linked to the DOM implementation, and that's not what you want (We also call that fragile tests). Imagine you want to add another div that encapsulate all the others --> your test would fail (but it should not)

A solid test would target a specific div using a class, a Component (better), or a data-selector (also better because also independent from your classes implementation).

I'll take your example with a little rework:

Here is the render of your component:

```
<div className="Card">
   <div>
     <div data-selector="Card-title">{this.props.title}</div>
   </div>
   <div data-selector="Card-description">{this.props.description}</div>
   <button data-selector="Card-button">{this.props.buttonLabel}</button>
</div>
```

And now the good way yo test it: (using Jest)

```
it('Should render a title', () => {
  const props = {title: 'Some Title'};
  const wrapper = shallow(<MyComponent {...props} />);

  const titleWrapper = wrapper.find({'data-selector': 'Card-title'});
  expect(titleWrapper).toHaveLength(1);
  expect(titleWrapper.text()).toEqual(props.title);
});
```

Even for the button it's better to target the data-selector: if tomorrow you decide to use a react Component instead of a regular button, your test won't fail :)